# svg animation not displaying properly in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

I've created a CSS SVG animation of a frame being drawn onto the stage. The animation works correctly, but there seems to be an issue mostly in Chrome. The stage should be blank before the animation begins and the frame, made up of 4 segments, "draws" in segment by segment. In some versions of Chrome, however, before the animation begins there are 4 dots on the stage. The dots are the beginning points of each segment of the frame and shouldn't be visible.

In a few versions of Chrome that I've tested it on (47.0.2526.106 on a Mac, 47.0.2526.83 on an Android phone, and 43.0.2357.130 for Windows), the dots are visible. In older versions of Chrome (43.0.2357.130 for Mac, for example) and in Safari and Firefox the dots are not visible. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue? Any help will be appreciated.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/sbxsz0mo/) is a working example in a jsfiddle.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
  <div id="bottomLeftPosition">
            <svg><path class="pathBottomLeft framePath" d="M127.504,105.451
                c1.394-0.461,0.629-2.404,0.735-3.859c0.047-0.719,0.826-1.225,0.368-2.021c-0.338-0.598-1.333-0.398-2.39-0.735
                c-1.424-0.442-1.931-1.087-3.493-0.735c-2.143,0.475-7.396,4.611-8.453,6.25c-0.674,1.041-1.501,3.322-1.471,4.227
                c0.045,1.363,2.036,4.655,2.573,5.146c2.036,1.852,6.769,2.986,10.107,2.389c1.715-0.307,2.97-1.578,4.593-1.654
                c2.084-2.389,4.381-4.564,6.066-7.352l0.887-5.713l-1.071-5.314c-1.286-3.615-4.104-5.696-6.064-8.637
                c-1.579-0.965-3.461-1.058-5.147-1.84c-0.75-0.352-1.254-1.148-2.021-1.47c-1.775-0.735-3.98-0.245-5.696-1.47
                c-7.427-0.858-13.187,0.994-19.665,2.021c-14.793,5.359-29.726,12.865-42.453,20.766c-1.011,0.628-2.022,1.426-3.125,2.021
                c-1.93,1.043-3.293,1.533-5.697,2.389c-1.256,0.445-2.39,1.38-3.492,1.654c-4.642,1.166-9.604-1.285-12.498-4.225
                c-0.934-2.758-2.573-5.451-2.389-9.926c0.077-1.852,1.01-3.538,0.551-5.329c3.186-8.179,6.616-16.249,11.578-23.708
                c0.415-0.627,1.226-1.041,1.655-1.654c0.643-0.934,0.872-2.266,1.47-3.307c0.551-0.98,1.547-1.7,2.022-2.573
                c1.592-2.911,2.389-7.168,2.94-10.66c0.245-1.547-0.261-2.925-0.368-4.595c-0.092-1.409,0.23-2.879,0.185-4.411
                c-0.092-3.768-0.766-8.071-1.287-11.946c-0.291-2.145-0.26-4.84-1.103-6.8c-1.057-2.466-3.277-3.538-4.594-6.065
                c-2.251-0.75-4.519-1.485-6.433-2.572L29.73,14.11c-2.634,0.214-3.967,1.777-6.065,2.94C21,20.665,13.879,30.804,18.152,35.98
                c2.205,2.665,4.456,6.249,8.821,4.228c0.583-2.144,4.028-3.905,5.513-6.616c0.199-0.368,0.153-1.011,0.368-1.471
                c0.367-0.75,0.995-1.24,1.103-1.837c0.062-0.367-0.336-3.89-0.551-4.595c-0.75-2.542-3.706-2.036-4.594,0"/></svg>
  </div>
  <div id="topLeftPosition">
    <svg><path class="pathTopLeft framePath" d=
      "M29.638,109.531c1.792-2.664,3.92-8.469,1.838-12.13c-0.75-0.123-1.087-0.55-1.654-0.919c-1.118-0.703-1.731-1.071-2.94-1.654
                c-1.348-0.643-0.919-0.489-2.573-0.551c-1.976-0.062-2.665,0.443-4.043,1.654c-2.604,2.297-5.146,5.514-5.513,9.373
                c-0.705,7.458,4.717,12.42,9.924,14.702c0,0,2.281,0.2,2.343,0.214c0.138,0,2.251-0.582,2.251-0.582
                c1.93-0.918,3.094-2.449,4.595-3.857c1.057-0.981,2.22-1.303,3.124-2.572c0.521-0.736,1.011-1.824,1.654-2.758
                c0.583-0.857,1.486-1.73,1.838-2.389c0.384-0.719,0.245-1.593,0.552-2.572c0.275-0.857,1.042-1.762,1.286-2.573
                c0.903-2.972,0.659-7.366,0.552-10.292c-0.261-7.488-2.405-13.509-4.778-19.481c-0.751-1.915-2.083-3.476-2.941-5.33
                c-0.628-1.362-1.087-2.817-1.838-4.226c-0.95-1.792-2.359-2.772-2.573-5.146c-2.374-3.553-3.584-7.903-4.962-12.129
                c-0.475-1.456-1.287-3.064-1.471-5.513c-0.367-4.992,1.976-9.327,3.86-13.417c1.271-2.772,2.71-5.252,4.41-6.799
                c5.989-5.438,16.847-8.333,26.648-8.088c4.794,0.123,9.909,0.581,14.152,2.021c1.486,0.506,3.032,1.286,4.595,1.837
                c1.593,0.552,3.384,0.98,4.779,1.654c1.838,0.889,3.553,2.39,5.329,3.492c3.095,1.915,5.667,3.048,8.086,5.331
                c2.543,2.404,4.442,5.482,6.802,7.902c2.557,2.635,5.713,4.012,8.453,6.249c2.863,0.812,5.729,1.624,7.902,3.124
                c11.579,2.635,21.748-2.113,25.729-9.924c0,0,1.47-9.266,0.919-11.548c0.046-0.72-1.103-4.809-1.103-4.809
                c-1.424-2.374-2.895-4.028-5.022-5.698c-0.949-0.827-3.568-2.803-6.785-1.179c-2.955,2.144-5.851,7.596-2.298,11.026
                c2.358,2.268,6.311,1.731,9.558,2.206"/></svg>
  </div>
  <div id="topRightPosition">
    <svg><path class="pathTopRight framePath" d="M25.065,32.641
                c0,0,4.334-2.696,4.518-2.833c2.696-1.869,5.728-2.864,6.065-6.616c-0.995-7.259-8.883-7.32-12.772-4.15
                c-2.849,2.312-5.391,7.473-5.391,12.512c0,2.021-0.015,5.223,0.919,7.352c0.674,1.532,2.925,3.706,4.962,4.411
                c0.719,0.246,1.776,0.124,2.572,0.368c1.761,0.536,2.451,1.363,5.33,1.103c6.371-0.567,12.023-1.516,17.827-2.94
                c1.257-0.307,2.052-0.842,3.309-1.287c1.593-0.582,3.385-0.582,4.963-1.103c2.894-0.965,5.773-2.375,8.637-3.492
                c3.033-1.179,6.126-2.205,9.005-3.492c6.294-2.818,12.649-7.03,19.113-9.557c2.528-0.995,5.054-1.562,7.167-3.124
                c0.675,0.061,1.195-0.031,1.654-0.184c4.624-2.926,12.865-3.645,19.113-3.676c1.041,0.612,2.129,1.179,3.676,1.286
                c3.047,2.007,6.77,4.793,8.637,8.822c1.656,3.553,2.145,7.888,2.574,12.314c0.229,2.451-0.385,5.314-0.367,7.903
                c0.107,13.768-7.704,24.688-11.763,35.653c-2.466,2.236-2.772,5.896-4.593,9.924c-0.322,0.721-0.995,1.286-1.287,2.021
                c-2.344,5.881-3.83,15.408-0.185,20.217c1.685,2.221,7.169,4.977,10.661,3.859c2.268-0.72,3.521-2.543,5.145-4.41
                c0.245-6.005-2.387-9.129-5.879-11.396c-1.104,0.309-1.93-0.211-2.757,0.369c-0.49,0.703-0.124,1.393-0.185,2.389"/></svg>
  </div>
  <div id="bottomRightPosition">
    <svg><path class="pathBottomRight framePath" d="
                M133.236,18.858c0.106,1.517-3.018,6.448,0.184,7.168c1.256,0.275,3.782-1.087,4.962-1.838c2.757-1.761,4.228-5.773,4.779-8.271
                c-0.981-2.189-2.282-4.793-4.595-5.88c-3.645-1.716-8.867-0.153-11.027,2.205c-2.45,2.68-4.41,7.979-4.778,13.049
                c-0.291,4.088,0.95,6.371,3.308,8.454c1.961,1.746,4.61,2.788,6.618,4.595c0.153,0.138,0.353,0.521,0.55,0.735
                c2.007,2.159,3.507,4.441,4.963,7.536c0.658,1.393,1.026,5.575,1.471,7.657c0.628,2.91,1.623,6.264,1.838,9.005
                c0.904,11.777-0.154,23.968-6.8,31.611c-1.731,1.163-3.309,2.647-5.147,3.858c-1.699,1.103-3.415,2.634-5.329,3.492
                c-0.873,0.382-2.006,0.382-2.94,0.733c-5.238,1.962-11.104,2.59-17.828,3.31c-4.762,0.521-8.898,0.949-14.52,1.103
                c-4.746,0.123-9.158,1.103-12.864-0.184c-3.69-0.153-6.708-2.129-10.475-2.205c-2.328-1.348-5.452-2.465-8.086-2.94
                c-1.731-1.808-5.299-1.257-7.167-2.206c-0.888-0.153-0.659,0.812-1.654,0.552c-1.501-0.644-3.033-1.257-4.779-1.654
                c-0.627-0.169-0.536-1.058-1.103-1.286c-2.971-0.904-4.961-3.554-7.718-4.596c-0.384-0.137-0.98,0.123-1.471,0
                c-0.949-0.229-1.898-1.147-2.756-1.285c-9.802-1.517-18.486,8.055-16.54,17.09c0.321,1.486,0.413,3.493,2.052,5.897
                c3.752,4.364,7.918,1.716,10.66-1.286c1.47-1.609,3.614-8.729,0.276-9.006c-2.85-0.23-5.391,3.338-5.882,3.491"/></svg>
  </div>
  <div id="border"></div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
}
#mainContainer{
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #fff;
}
#border{ 
    position:absolute; 
    width:298px; 
    height:598px; 
    border:solid 1px #000; 
}
#bottomLeftPosition{
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:231px;
}
#topLeftPosition{
    position:absolute;
    left:9px;
    top:123px;
}
#topRightPosition{
    position:absolute;
    left:140px;
    top:116px;
}
#bottomRightPosition{
    position:absolute;
    left:130px;
    top:226px;
}
.framePath {
    width:160px;
    height:130px;
    fill:none;
    stroke:#000;
    stroke-width:3;
    stroke-linecap:round;
    stroke-miterlimit:10;
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
}
.pathBottomLeft {
    animation: dash 1.7s linear 1.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: dash 1.7s linear 1.5s forwards;
    -moz-animation: dash 1.7s linear 1.5s forwards;
}
.pathTopLeft {
    animation: dash 1.7s linear 2.2s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: dash 1.7s linear 2.2s forwards;
    -moz-animation: dash 1.7s linear 2.2s forwards;
}
.pathTopRight {
    animation: dash 1.7s linear 2.9s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: dash 1.7s linear 2.9s forwards;
    -moz-animation: dash 1.7s linear 2.9s forwards;
}
.pathBottomRight {
    animation: dash 1.7s linear 3.5s forwards;
    -webkit-animation: dash 1.7s linear 3.5s forwards;
    -moz-animation: dash 1.7s linear 3.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }

  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't necessarily think this is a bug, but it should certainly be fixed. Because there is a line with what seems to be a length of 0, you'd think it'd be invisible. But in these builds of Chrome, a line with a length of 0 and a positive stroke-width, will render. Just like how the browser will still render a div when it has been given a `height of 0` but also `a border thicker than 0`.

If you want to solve the issue, You can add something like `visibility: hidden;` or `opacity: 0;` to `.framePath`, and then add the opposite to the animation (at 0% **and** 100%)

Comment: zero length lines are supposed to render if the stroke-linecap is round or square (but not if it's butt). Seems more like a Firefox/Safari bug to me.

Comment: @RobertLongson - This hasn't been an issue for me in Firefox or Safari. At least with the versions that I tested.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, their display seems incorrect.

Comment: @RobertLongson - Ah, gotcha. I get what you mean now. Good to know if that is the case.